# hadoop hive: way to give mapper memory range

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, mapreduce

Currently I am using Hive setting `mapreduce.map.memory.mb=10240` along with `mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx8192m`to give the required memory for mapper.

But with data size growing every day, I have to increase this setting every once in a while after checking on error `container is running beyond virtual memory limits`.

Is there a way to specify some min and max memory for mapper where Hive itself will first try with the minimum memory configuration and then increase it in steps if needed?

Comment: You're using MapReduce execution engine instead of Tez or Spark?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. We are using MapReduce currently.

Comment: Okay, using other execution engines will save some memory, but if not, you'll have to increase your YARN container sizes, as well as those listed. And I doubt Hive / the JVM autoscales itself during runtime. At least, in my experience I have yet to see that feature.